# How to use the documentation on the Gradle DSL (domain specific language)?

Tags: c++, gradle, native

I'm currently a few days into setting up my mixed java/cpp multi-module gradle project. While I admit being new to groovy &Co, it seems every step of the way I need to find an exact example of what I'm trying to do, otherwise I cannot progress.

Q: Please can anyone tell me how to read this [Gradle DSL page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.nativeplatform.NativeLibrarySpec.html#org.gradle.nativeplatform.NativeLibrarySpec:static)? I'm trying to make my library compile as static-only (not shared) and even though I have used `baseName` and see `static` and `shared` properties documented on the page, I can't for the life of me understand how to use them. My code is:

```
components {
    api(NativeLibrarySpec) {
        sources {
            cpp {
                source {
                    srcDir "src/main/stuff"
                    include "**/*.cpp"
                }
            }
        }

        baseName "mylibrary"
        static "true"    <-- what to write here??
        shared "false"    <-- ??
    }
}
```

Comment: I've not used gradle for cpp but perhaps a [search through the sources on github](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/search?q=NativeLibrarySpec&unscoped_q=NativeLibrarySpec) might find a test case which can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look around and it seems that you should try that :

```
components {
    api(NativeLibrarySpec) {
        sources {
            cpp {
                source {
                    srcDir "src/main/stuff"
                    include "**/*.cpp"
                }
            }
        }

        binaries {
            all {
                lib library: "mylibrary", linkage: "static"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

edit :

[`all`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/model/ModelMap.html#all-org.gradle.api.Action-) is a method from the `ModelMap` interface, returned by the [`getBinaries`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/platform/base/VariantComponentSpec.html#getBinaries--) method. It says : *Applies the given action to each item in the collection*

`ModelMap` uses `BinarySpec` as parameter so the parameter of `all` is an `Action<BinarySpec>` object.

So the `Action` class (functional interface) defines one method `execute(BinarySpec spec)`. The method [`lib`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/nativeplatform/NativeBinarySpec.html#lib-java.lang.Object-) is from `NativeBinarySpec`

> void lib(Object library)
>
> Adds a library as input to this binary.
>
> This method accepts the following types:
>
> ```
> A NativeLibrarySpec
> A NativeDependencySet
> A Map containing the library selector.
> ```
>
> The Map notation supports the following String attributes:
>
> ```
> project: the path to the project containing the library (optional, defaults to current project)
> library: the name of the library (required)
> linkage: the library linkage required ['shared'/'static'] (optional, defaults to 'shared')
> ```

So, to sum things up, `mylibrary` is added as input to all binaries.

Comment: OK that's fair. But I'm waiting for a hint on how I'm supposed to grasp the syntax `lib library: "..."`. What do we have there, function calls, assignments? In a language where function-call parantheses are optional, how can one tell what we're looking at, hence what to look for in Gradle Reference??

Comment: I added an explanation.